# Check product has more than one option in dropdown Magento

Tags: magento, product

HI i need something **unusual** , i want like

> if my product has more than one option value
>
> than it should show in dropdown
>
> otherwise if it has only one option value
>
> than i need to show without dropdown or as a text only.

Please suggest me how can i do this.

like like if

```
<select name="select_box" id="select_box">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="tow">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="three">4</option>
    <option value="three">5</option>
    <option value="three">6</option>
</select>
```

the dropdown has more than one opton than i need to show the above dropdown and if the

```
  <select name="select_box" id="select_box">
        <option value="one">optionname only</option>
    </select>
```

dropdown has one option than i need to show  `optionname only` as a text.This will not be a require field.

Comment: Can you post an example to make it clearer?

Comment: hi i have edit my question please check that thanks

Comment: You can do this by custom php..if there is only 1 option the get the option and put the value as text( product->getAttributeText('attribute_id')) in a Text Field.

Comment: thats what i want to know , can you please tell me in which file i have to place this check and how

Answer (score 0):

3-4 files are included in this process.

You can see that by enabling `"Template path hints" from admin->settings->advanced->developer`.

anyway check these files

if its a dropdown the you can change in this file (Remember do changes in your theme not in base)

`frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml`

`Another files in this process(check xml)`

`frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml`
`frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml`
`frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml`

Another way:

Goto

`App/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`

here find `getValuesHtml()` and check the code and edit as per your need
`(DO NOT EDIT CORE FILES ALWAYS OVERRIDE FOR EDITING PURPOSE)`

Comment: i know about these files but i know in which file i need to place check. In select file i cant see any foreach to check it has more than one value on dropdown